# SQL - Syntax Error in FROM Clause (JOIN)

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax, oledb, ms-access-2013

Just beginning to experiment with the JOIN clause so I can display data from across multiple tables in a gridview. However, I can't for the life of me work out what my error is here. I've tried switching around the order of tables called, columns called and the such to no success. This, I think, is the closest to working I can get the statement. It's basically a straight copy of a supposedly working statement, yet still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.
(I'm using VB.Net to code, Access '13 as the database (which might be part of the problem; I've read it's very finicky about syntax) and developing with VS 2013.)

@tim: as requested, here's the full sub.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    If cbSearchType.Text = "Guest Surname" Then

        Dim searchSQL As String = "SELECT bookings.bookingStartDate, bookings.bookingEndDate, guests.guestFirstName, guests.guestSurname, locations.locationName FROM bookings JOIN guests ON guests.guestID = bookings.guestID JOIN locations ON locations.locationID = bookings.locationID WHERE guests.guestSurname = @guestSurname"

        Dim searchCommand = New OleDbCommand(searchSQL, globalVariables.objConnection)
        Dim searchAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(searchSQL, globalVariables.objConnection)
        Dim searchDataTable As New DataTable

        searchCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("guestSurname", tbSearchTextBox.Text)
        searchAdapter.SelectCommand = searchCommand
        searchAdapter.Fill(searchDataTable)

        globalVariables.objConnection.Open()
        searchAdapter.Fill(searchDataTable)
        gvSearchResults.DataSource = searchDataTable
        globalVariables.objConnection.Close()

    ElseIf cbSearchType.Text = "Location" Then

    ElseIf cbSearchType.Text = "Booking Start Date" Then

    ElseIf cbSearchType.Text = "Booking End Date" Then

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: "Syntax Error in FROM Clause"

Comment: Might be `"...WHERE guests.guestSurnmae = '" + @guestSurname + "'" - i.e., if `guestSurname` is a char or varchar field, you'll need to quote it with single quotes `'`.  The other thing to check is that you have spaces between keywords (`FROM`, `WHERE`, etc).  Can you post the actual VB.NET code you're using?

Comment: Don't work with Access much anymore, but you'll probably want to use `"@guestSurname"` instead of `"guestSurname"` in your `Parameters.AddWithValue`.  Not 100% sure Access supports named parameters either.  Try stepping through the debugger and seeing what the text of the `OleDbCommand` is after you add the parameter - that should show you if it's correct or not.

Comment: I was just reading that Access doesn't accept unqualified JOIN's, so I changed to INNER JOIN and received...

Comment: @tvellalott - Add the error to your original question.  Comments don't support code and formatting very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, you need to specify `INNER JOIN`.  You also need parentheses when there are multiple joins.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT b.bookingStartDate, b.bookingEndDate, g.guestFirstName, g.guestSurname, l.locationName
FROM (bookings as b INNER JOIN
      guests as g
      ON g.guestID = b.guestID) INNER JOIN
     locations as l
     ON l.locationID = b.locationID
WHERE g.guestSurname = @guestSurname;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except that my gridview shows duplicate results for some reason.

Comment: Ugh, had searchAdapter.Fill(searchDataTable) twice.